# Return object on duplicate insert in datastructure?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am currently inserting objects into a Hashset (nodes into a graph). And whenever I insert a duplicate I get false returned. That is great feedback but I much rather see the object returned so I can work with it. Right now I can come up with either:

- Insert the object and if it's a duplicate iterate over the set and compare again to retrieve the object. So very inefficient.
- Iterate over it at first and insert when it's unique otherwise edit the object in the set. For my purpose this is even less efficient since I expect not many duplicates.

Am I missing something?

I could use a `Map<K,V>` and use the same object for the key and value. But this will probably use more memory then Set? But I'm still missing functionality for the map. `hashMap.put(key, value)` will always return the value. So how do I know when the value is duplicate? In this scenario I still have to do a lookup for each  pair I want to insert.

So perhaps there I overlooked a datastructure that suits my needs? I simply want to insert objects  and on a duplicate entry work with the object already in the data structure. Since afaik, if the datastructure already knows there is a duplicate it should also have access to this duplicate and I would really like that object pretty please.

- I really do need the object in the data, I had people say I already have the object since it's a duplicate. But if I change that object the object in the set will not change.
- Don't worry, I generate the Hashcode from the coordinates and these are final (immutable). I will add connections to other nodes to it and they will not alter the hash or sort order.
- I really rather not use the iterator. There is a reason why the datastructure contain the word `hash`. They work a lot faster by using tree lookups and other stuff I should not talk about since I do not know enough of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea with `Map` may suit your needs.

> I could use a Map and use the same object for the key and value.
>   But this will probably use more memory then Set?

`HashSet` is implemented through `HashMap` - so there will be no difference.

> But I'm still missing functionality for the map. hashMap.put(key,
>   value) will always return the value.

It will return `null` if there was no mapping. So unless you need to store nulls, you can implement it like this:

```
T duplicate = map.put(newValue, newValue);
if (duplicate != null) {
    map.put(duplicate, duplicate); // if you need old object in case of duplicate
    processDuplicate(newValue, duplicate);
}
```

Comment: Totally missed that put returns null if there was no duplicate.  Now wondering if I should remove the coordinates from the node and just use these as the key.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Set doesn't seem to be the way to go. The Set API is optimized for checking if an element is in the set or not (`contains`) and for traversal (via `Iterator`), but not for element retrieval.

Map seems to a better fit for your case, as you can also fast check if an element is there, and also retrieve an element if you need it. However, it seems a bit odd to use the same object as key and value - don't you have anything that could be used as a key? As you are programming graphs, don't the nodes have an id or something that uniquely identifies them? How about using these "coordinates" you mentioned as key? This may give you more flexibility and better performance.

By the way, the Map `put` method returns the old object if there was an object with the same key, or `null` otherwise. If it helps you, instead of checking if an object is in the map before the `put`, you could check if the object was there *after* the `put` - and do something to correct the map back to its original state.